# Displaying only the items that match the input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop the logic for a menu box that lists out some checkbox items and above it is a search bar, so when the user types one of the items name, that item with checkbox is the only one that appears:

[image]]

This is the logic that I have worked out so far:

```
const fetchLabel = (searchTerm) => {
  const searchedValues = [
    ...document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"),
  ].map((searchTerm) => searchTerm.value);
  console.log(searchedValues);
  return searchedValues;
};

const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  let searchedValues: string[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < searchedValues.length; i++) {
    const element = searchedValues[i];
    if (element === target) {
      console.log("this works");
    }
  }
  // fetchLabel(target.value);
});
```

I am stuck on the if conditional part of it, moreover, I am not even sure `map()` is the best array helper to use. I tried implementing `filter()` but I was unable to make any headway with that either.

Comment: Can you please post the html as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to just filter the checkboxes by whether their value includes the searched text?  If that is the case, you would want to iterate over the options, check if the value includes the search term, and toggle the display property:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input[name=search]");

input.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  const search = input.value.toLowerCase();
  [
    ...document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"),
  ].forEach((checkbox) => {
      checkbox.parentElement.style.display = checkbox.value.toLowerCase().includes(search) ? null : 'none';
  });
});
```

```html
<input name="search"/>

<label><input type="checkbox" value="Foo"/> Foo</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Bar" /> Bar</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="FooBar" /> FooBar</label>
```

Comment: Why a comma before `]` ? I mean  ...document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"), <--

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner I just always have a comma after each item in an array - if you add an item later on you a) won't cause an error because you forgot to add a comma to the previous line, and b) in your git diff, it won't show that line as changed, it will only show the new line, which is cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. That was new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with while I was receiving the above answer in the background which I plan to mark off as the answer:

```
// Checkbox Menu
const checkboxMenu = document.querySelector(".checkbox");
checkboxMenu.innerHTML = `
<nav class="panel">
  <div class="panel-block">
    <p class="control has-icons-left">
      <input class="input" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search">
      <span class="icon is-left">
        <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a class="panel-block is-active">
    <input type="checkbox" id="density" name="density" value="density">
      Density
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="panel-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="holc" name="" value="holc">
      HOLC
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="panel-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tcac" name="" value="tcac">
      TCAC
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="panel-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="population" name="" value="population">
      Population
    </a></li>
    <li><a class="panel-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="zoning" name="" value="zoning">
      Zoning
    </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
`;

const fetchLabel = () => {
  let input, filter, ul, li, a, i, textValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    textValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (textValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};

const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  fetchLabel();
});
```